# Change checked state of a material-ui switch onChange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, react-state, material-table

I have implemented a material-ui table with a column that renders material-ui switch component for each of the table rows. I'm able to successfully pass data for the switches using table data (rowData arg), which you can see below. Since each material-ui element maintains its own state, I assume that setting 'checked' this way sets the states as well. I also have a handleChange method to change the state onChange. I however can't see the switch happening in the UI.

```
  const [switchState, setswitchState] = useState({});
 
  const handleChange = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setswitchState({ ...switchState, [evt.target.name]: evt.target.checked });
  };

  <MaterialTable
    columns={[
      {
        title: "Name",
        field: "DisplayName",
      },
      {
        title: "Switch Control",
        field: "checked",
        render: (rowData) =>
        <Typography component="div">
          <Grid component="label" container alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
            <Grid item>On</Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <AntSwitch
                name="cb"
                onChange={handleChange}
                checked={rowData.checked}/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>off</Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Typography>
      }
    ]}
    data={data}
    options={{
      search: false,
      paging: false,
    }}
  />
```

I also tried setting the state dynamically on render of each row/switch as,

```
const dyCheckState = (rd: any) => {
  setswitchState({ ...switchState, [rd.name]: rd.checked});
  return rd.checked;
};

<AntSwitch
   name={rowData.DisplayName}
   onChange={handleChange}
   checked={dyCheckState(rowData)}
/>
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How is rowData.checked related to switchState? I don't see rowData being updated anywhere, Re-render will only happen if rowData is updated in some form

Comment: @Ashu I'm assuming checked=rowData.checked will set the state for a switch based on the 'name' of each switch. That is why I'm trying to set the switchState in my handleChange(). I also tried checked = {rowData.checked}, but that din't work. Now I have put both of it in my onChange() and it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using rowData in state itself and not mutate it directly.

Please follow the below given example

```
 const [rowDataState, setRowDataState] = useState(rowData);


 // Then use rowDataState in here something like this

 <AntSwitch
    name={rowDataState.DisplayName}
    onChange={(evt)=>{
      setswitchState({ ...switchState, [evt.target.name]: evt.target.checked 
      });
      setRowDataState({ ...rowDataState, checked: evt.target.checked }); 
    }}
    checked={rowDataState.checked}
  />
```

Also, I would recommend moving these both into a different handler function in the component and then pass it as an onChangeHandler to the AntSwitch.

Answer (score 0):

Set switchState and also the rowData.checked. However, someone who can give more details on this one can put your answers up.

```
     <AntSwitch
        name={rowData.DisplayName}
        onChange={(evt)=>{
          setswitchState({ ...switchState, [evt.target.name]: evt.target.checked });
          rowData.checked = evt.target.checked;
        }}
        checked={rowData.checked}
      />
```